# Which ERPs Support Effective Dating and what are the Alternatives?

Tags: sql, taxonomy, erp, peoplesoft

In PeopleSoft, Effective Dating is used to maintain historical *and* future data in the *same* table as current data.  To find the *current* row in an Effective Dated table, you would look for the row with the most recent Effective Date that is *not* in the future.

As an example, suppose I had the following database table and it was August 24th, 2016:
[image]

Then on August 24th, 2016, I would compute EmpId 102’s *current* salary as $100,000 via a pseudo-query like this (1):

```
select * from ps_Employee_Salaries ES where 
(ES.EmpId = 102) and 
   (ES.Effective_Date = (
      select max(Effective_Date) from ps_Employee_Salaries ES_ED
      where (
         (ES.EmpId = ES_ED.EmpId) and
         (ES_ED.Effective_Date <= ‘August 24th, 2016’)
      )
   )
);
```

Similarly, I would also compute EmpId 103’s *current* salary as $70,000 by running the above pseudo-query and replacing 102 with 103.

This Effective Dating approach works well in *most* cases but it can be non-performant and confusing for complex queries that require outer joins across numerous Effective Dated tables.

Can someone describe to me the following:

1. What other ERP systems (if any) use an Effective Dating concept similar to the one above?
   and
2. What alternatives exist other than Effective Dating for ERP systems that wish to maintain historical and future data?

The 1985 ACM Article “A Taxonomy of Time in Databases” by Snodgrass and Ahn is the only Non-PeopleSoft article that presently comes to my mind when describing approaches of this nature.

(1) – A more through description of *PeopleSoft* Effective Dated queries can be found here (among other places):
http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/effective-dates-sequence-status

Comment: With regards to question 2, it depends on your constraints. For example you could move all non-current data into a datawarehouse, but then application inquiries would only yield current info. Is that a constraint? With regards to question 1, I know that SAP also uses this approach.

Comment: Performance is really a different question. Just use a highly spec'd server. The real question is system complexity. But if you're modelling complex business process, the system to model it is also complex. The effective data approach is about the best one there is to model this situation form a database perspective.

Comment: I recently realized this question falls under the topic of Type_2 Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD). This technique has apparently been around for a **very** long time. Taygan Rifat has a March 21, 2022 blog post titled "Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD)" that describes what I'm after. I don't agree with Rifat (and many others) that the SurrogateKey is actually necessary, but I agree with the large majority of the content. Mr. Rifat's post is currently located here:
https://www.taygan.co/blog/2022/03/21/slowly-changing-dimensions-scd

Comment: SCD's are for analytics / data warehouses - they support analytics. You're asking about ERP's (applications) in this question. If you only want the data for analytics, and not for a direct enquiry screen in your app then yep SCD is a great solution. If you are building an analytics solution / star schema then surrogate keys solve many problems and they are pretty critical to the design. If you are just putting the effective dated data back into an isolated ERP database, then surrogate keys are likely unecessary.